# Custom Header for Date Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, material-design

I use pickadate.js ( http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/ )

I try to create a custom header to display a chosen date similar to Material Design Date Picker - http://materializecss.com/forms.html#date-picker

I've read the documentation of pickadate.js but there is no mention about such a customization.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Like that dude :

```
onRender: function () {
                var year = $('.datepicker').pickadate('picker').get('highlight', 'yyyy');
                var day = $('.datepicker').pickadate('picker').get('highlight', 'dd');
                var month = $('.datepicker').pickadate('picker').get('highlight', 'mm');
                console.log(year, day, month);

                $('.picker__header').prepend('<div class="picker__date-display"><div class="picker__weekday-display">[current day label]</div><div class="picker__month-display"><div>[current month]</div></div><div class="picker__day-display"><div>'+day+'</div></div><div    class="picker__year-display"><div>'+year+'</div></div></div>');
            }
```

see here http://jsfiddle.net/ctx8ec9L/28/

Comment: ok I did it for you : http://jsfiddle.net/ctx8ec9L/29/
don't forget to check resolve issue :)

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks

Comment: What if I am defining a number of datepickers with different init options? Do I have to define the header like this for each?

Answer (score 0):

I do this http://jsfiddle.net/ctx8ec9L/26/.

```
 $('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
    ,
    onRender: function() {
     $('.picker__header').prepend('<div class="picker__date-display"><div           class="picker__weekday-display">[current day label]</div><div class="picker__month-display"><div>[current month]</div></div><div class="picker__day-display"><div>[current days]</div></div><div    class="picker__year-display"><div>[current year]</div></div></div>');
 }
  });
```

I think you can get current day, label day, month and year with amsul.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It was very helpful, thanks. Now I'm trying to get a selected date and display it. I try to use amsul get method ( http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/#method-get ) but I cannot figure out hot to make it works with your code. COuld you give me one more hint? Thank you in advanced

Comment: Here is a stating point `$('.datepicker').pickadate('picker').get('highlight', 'yyyy/mm/dd')` http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/#method-get-highlight

Comment: Greg, could you take a look at my comment at the bottom of this topic?

Answer (score 0):

This one is based on @Greg's answer. I modified it to be multipurpose.
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctx8ec9L/34/)

```
function populatePickadateHeader(elem){
    var year = $(elem).pickadate('picker').get('highlight', 'yyyy');
    var day = $(elem).pickadate('picker').get('highlight', 'dd');
    var month = $(elem).pickadate('picker').get('highlight', 'mmm');
    var labelday = $(elem).pickadate('picker').get('highlight', 'dddd');
    console.log(year, day, month,labelday);

    $(elem + '_root' + ' .picker__header').prepend('<div class="picker__date-display"><div class="picker__weekday-display">'+labelday+'</div><div class="picker__month-display"><div>'+month+'</div></div><div class="picker__day-display"><div>'+day+'</div></div><div    class="picker__year-display"><div>'+year+'</div></div></div>');
}
```

Use it in initialization like

```
 $('#inputDatetime').pickadate({
     selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
     selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
     onRender: function () {
         populatePickadateHeader('#inputDatetime');        
     }
 });
```